# Order to install rvm, ruby, gem, rails, juggernaut

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation, rvm

I've been doing it over and over again on my Ubuntu1104 machine and something always keeps driving me nuts, like:

```
The program 'ruby' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

And that even after installing ruby, which clearly stated "installed successfully". 
Also:

```
rvm list
```

tells me:

```
rvm rubies

    ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ i686 ]
```

This:

```
which ruby
which gem
```

returns nothing.

So can someone please state the correct order to install ruby and it's gems like rails and juggernaut. I believe that I have trouble with paths (the system can't find successfully installed goodies) and rights (sometimes have to sudo and sometimes not, wich might be the cause for the path trouble I have). So please also give clear instructions on where to install and which rights to use.

I thought it's RVM first (as stated in http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/):

```
1) bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
2) bash < <(curl -sk https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
3) echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

And then Ruby (which also installs gem):

```
4) rvm 1.9.2
```

And then the gems like rails and juggernaut

```
5) gem install rails
6) gem install juggernaut
...
```

Unfortunately I get a message as posted above, 'gem not installed' and 'ruby not installed'.

Plus you can also install ruby first and then install RVM as a gem... confusing...

Cheers mates!
Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you did not intsalled rmv correctly:
what does

```
user$ type rvm | head -1
rvm is a function
```

If this is not what you see, then do :

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bashrc
```

restart bash and try again

after do

```
rvm --default use 1.9.2
```

Comment: rmv --default use 1.9.2 -- Plain and simple... That's what was missing, now I can use rby and gem! Thanks! (can't vote up, I'm missing 1 rep point :) )

Answer (score 1):

make sure you `rvm use 1.9.2` in case it doesn't default

Answer (score 0):

`rvm` should be installed first.

After that the gems. I don't see how rvm could be a gem, but could be.

If you type `which ruby` after selecting a ruby via rvm then something is wrong with your rvm installation; start over by deleting your home `.rvm` directory.

Verify the expected command is in your `.bashrc` (on Ubuntu I don't have a `.bash_profile`, that's more an OS X thing, but could be a version or setup difference rather than wrong). You can see what files are in your home directory.